# How to convert a Hex-value to float in modbus-protocol using C#

Tags: modbus

i am using the modbus-protocoll to retrieve an analog-value from a module.
On the webpanel i can see that the value is 09FD in Hex and 0.780 in float.
The function returns only the 09FD into C# and must be manuall converted to the float-value.

For this there is a convert-function in the modbus-dll:
public static float GetSingle(
    ushort highOrderValue,
    ushort lowOrderValue
)

But what part of "09FD" must be set to the two ushorts?
I dont figure out how to pass it to retrieve the double-value.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The values returned in the register are integers, scaled in some way to permit representation of the fractional floating point values. You will need to review the documentation of your module to determine how to scale (and possibly offset) the result to convert it into actual engineering units.

If you don't have documentation, then you could retrieve multiple values from the web panel, plot them and fit a line through them to estimate the parameters used to scale the output value.

The `GetSingle()` function you reference applies if the values are represented in true floating point form (and passed in two adjacent integers) by the device. Your example with only a single integer suggests this is not the case.